# Setting up sftp/ftp for OCI wordpress

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, wordpress, oracle

I’ve been following the oracle tutorial for setting up wordpress (https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/wp-on-ubuntu/01-summary.htm), now when I want to download a theme, it says I need give the sftp/ftp details. Does this mean

that I can just setup an sftp server and use that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this message because the WordPress `wp-content` directory is not writable by the webserver.

An alternative would be giving the webserver direct write access to the directory. Doing that will also enable automatic updates of plugins, themes. If you enable write access to the whole WordPress directory it can even update itself automatically.

Write access is also needed to upload files you want to use on you website (images, videos etc.).

Comment: I'm quite new to this, how can I do this? Should I just change the right perms for the directory?

Comment: That's one option. Another would be ACL.

Answer (score 0):

On most Ubuntu releases openssh is already installed, and openssh also includes sftp.
Make sure to use secure and strong authentication protocols